# Rendering binary ms/doc in UIWebView is blank

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2, salesforce-ios-sdk

I'm attempting to pull down a binary file (from Salesforce) and display it in a UIWebView.  However, it it showing up blank.  Here's the code I'm currently running:

```
class SRAFileViewController: UIViewController {
    var webView: UIWebView!
    var fileData: NSData!
    var fileType: String!

    convenience init(fileData: NSData!, fileType: String!, title: String!){
        self.init()
        self.fileType = fileType
        self.fileData = fileData
        self.title = title
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "close")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationItem.title = self.title
        webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView.delegate = self
        let tempData = NSData(bytes: fileData.bytes, length: fileData.length)
        webView.loadData(tempData, MIMEType: self.fileType, textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost")!)
    }

    func close(){
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However, the `UIWebView` comes up blank.

The value of `fileData` is `<d0cf11e0 a1b11ae1...00000000 0000c700 00000000>` and the `fileType` is `application/msword`

Does anyone have some ideas how to get this to render properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see at least the binary data of your file, if the webview can't properly render it.

However,

1. `self.view.frame` might not be properly set in `viewDidLoad`. Try setting the `webView` frame in viewWillAppear also.
2. I don't see where you added the `webView` to the `view`.

Comment: Damn, think I was just staring at code for too long. Forgot to add it to the view. That's for the second pair of eyes. Have a vote.